# Put small images on the top of UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I've got a UIImageView in a page that gets its image from the Interface builder and I'm trying to put small icons on the top of it (it's a small map and I want to put icons on it). I know it's probably very simple but I tried to look it up in the documentation but it pretty much got me more confused.

Comment: I just figured out that the UIImageView should be allocated separately and added to the view as subview

Answer (score 1):

Using Interface Builder, can't you just drag a UIImageView into an existing UIImageView?  In effect, you end up with one UIImageView embedded within another.

You should also be able to easily set the hidden property of the "small map" UIImageView in code, depending on if that UIImageView is needed or not.

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.

- Let It Be Known

Comment: I just figured out that when you add a UIImageView with IB, it considers it as a simple uiview. So by simply creating new UIImageViews and loading the images in it and then adding it as a subview to the self.view, it gets added to the view dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

you could compose your own UIView by adding both the large and small UIViewImage views.

I have illustrated my approach below with the Pseudocode .

```
-(id) initwithFrame:(CGRect) frame
{

  if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
  {

   iContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

   [iContainer addSubViews:iLargerUIImageView];
   [iContainer addSubViews:iSmallUIImageView];

   [self.view addSubViews:iContainer];
  }
  return self;
}
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect myRect = self.frame;
    iContainer.frame = myRect;
    //Give the location to iLargerUIImageView as per your requirement.
     iLargerUIImageView.frame = CGRectMake(...,...,...,...);
    //Give the location to iSmallUIImageViewas per your requirement.  
    iSmallUIImageView.frame = CGRectMake(...,...,...,...);

}

-(void) dealloc
{
  [iContainer release];
  [iLargerUIImageView release];
  [iSmallUIImageView release];
}
```

Comment: thanks, the problem was that I was trying to get the image view which didn't exist... when i added the new uiimageview to the self.view it started working, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

try this code:

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:kBckGndImag];

```
if(!backgroundImageView){
    UIImage *imageName  =   [UIImage imageNamed:kpointsChartBig];

    backgroundImageView =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, imageName.size.width, imageName.size.height)]; 

    backgroundImageView.image=imageName;

    [backgroundImageView setTag:kBckGndImag];

    [pointImageView addSubview:backgroundImageView];

    [backgroundImageView release];
}

UIImageView *foregroundImageView = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:kForGndImage];

if(!foregroundImageView){
    foregroundImageView =       [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kpointsColoredChartBig]];

    foregroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;

    foregroundImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [pointImageView addSubview:foregroundImageView];

    [foregroundImageView release];
}
```

Comment: one  think i would like to ask,You missed to set frame for foregroundimage

Comment: Yeah you have hawk eye.                                                          foregroundImageView.frame=CGRectMake(15, 15, backgroundImageView.frame.size.width*mPercent/100, foregroundImageView.bounds.size.height);